# Short story where man awakens in a grave, escapes and then realizes he has become a ghost

Tags: story-identification, ghost

I remember reading a gist of some famous ghost story/novel in a newspaper in my childhood. It was published in the newspaper because the time when it was published in the newspaper was Halloween. So the newspaper tried to give previews of some globally famous ghost stories/novels. The gist of this particular story goes like this:

> A man suddenly awakes and discovers himself confined in a grave. He got surprised. Slowly he remembers he was with his friends somewhere. Those friends tried to kill him by some way (may be poisoning). They thought he was dead, but in reality he was not. He thinks himself to be lucky to get saved some way. At the same time he becomes enraged against his friends and promises himself to avenge this unjust by killing them.
>
> So he remembers he had the key of his car. It had some sort of knife embedded within it. He searches for it and found it. With the use of that small knife and with great toil finally he succeeds to get out of the grave.
>
> Delightedly, he runs for his home to meet with his wife and inform her everything. So he reaches his house running and presses the bell. But surprisingly, nobody opens the door. He knew a trick to open the door. He applied it and entered his house. Then he went to his bedroom where he found his wife is sitting there anxiously. He called her but she did not look at him. Being surprised, he tried to touch her. But he could not. In this way slowly, he understands that it is not his physical form, but his ghost form. He has become a GHOST after his death!! What will he do now?

So this is the story. I read it a long time ago and it left a great impression on my mind. If somebody can identify it, it would be of great help.

Comment: This seems to be a relatively generic horror/ghost story trope. I'm not sure you'll be able to find a definitive version and author.

Comment: I think this question could do with a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 2):

Similar sounding story is "[A Fine and Private Place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Fine_and_Private_Place)" by Peter Beagle (sp).  No murders, but it's about waking up in a cemetery as a ghost.

Comment: The plotline really doesn't match.